# Android autocomplete textview on click item

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want to use `AutoCompleteTextview` for a `list` I have. I am using also an `Adapter` where I add the `list`. I want to print the element I click on. I use the following code but it does not work.

```
myAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    String selected;
    boolean click = false;                  
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parentView,View selectedItemView,int position, long id) {
        //code
    }
}
```

Also how to disable the ability to write in the `AutoCompleteTextview`? I don't want to write anything. I just want to print a list and select an element from it (including the first element).

Here is the layout xml file.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/myautocomplete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.95"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but, if you want to print a clickable list, the proper way of doing it is by using a ListView, not an AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: I see. thank you. Can you please help me qwith a listview where i can attach to each list element a picture? how to do this?please help. thank you

Comment: Of course a Spinner is faster and seems to match your needs. AutocompleteTextView is used if you want to help the user with values to use.

Comment: using the spinner i cannot select the first element. i've tried it. I need to be able to select the first element. also can a spinner have associated to each element an image?

Comment: @cosmincalistru can you help me with how to select the first element from a spinner?

Comment: the first element can't be selected? that's odd. concerning the image part i think that's possible.

Comment: maybe [this link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/) could help you with what you want

Comment: can i add to each element from a spinnerlist a picture? I also just want to display every time the first element from the list. how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to write anything on `autoCompleteTextView` and select items, you have to implement the `SPINNER` is more great

put this on your xml file

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />
```

in your code

```
ArrayAdapter quartadapter = new ArrayAdapter(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, CONSTANT.LISTPAIMENT);
quartadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
sp.setAdapter(quartadapter);
```

after you can use

```
sp.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    String selected;
    boolean click = false;                  
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parentView,View selectedItemView,int position, long id) {
        //code
    }
});
```